# mysql low speed after an update replace string

Tags: mysql

have 500k k2 articles(joomla), localhost, xampp, joomla 3,
every thing was good, both site & mysql admin,

i just did an update string (take 3 hours to complete):

```
UPDATE `#_k2_items` SET `introtext`= replace(`introtext`, '_70.jpg', '_140.jpg')
```

then the speed decreased madly (both site & mysql admin).

1-what to do now to increase speed?

2- if i change the type of the table 'id' type (because i have max 2millions of rows), does any increase in speed happens?

Comment: What queries specifically are slow? Is the site slower because it is now serving bigger images?

Comment: You could try adding a where clause so it only finds the rows where the introtext contains what you want to change. Currently this query attempts the replace on every row

Comment: i do not consider about the update query time, because i needed to do it just one time. my problem is now!. all speeds decreased.

Comment: add show create table please

Comment: Could be a fulltext index, that needs to be reconstructed

Comment: update query was so slow, but passed. now every query specially select queries (front end website) are very slow

Comment: fulltext index? how to reconstruct ?

Comment: i guess the problem is fulltext index repair, because i replaced the strings in introtext and fulltext of the articles. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MySQL table, having been massively updated, probably needs to be [optimized.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html)

You probably have access to phpmyadmin through your hosting service.

If so, you can try to optimize your table.

First, make a backup of your data base.  If you don't know how to do that, stop now, find out how, and do it, before you do anything else. (Or you may be sorry, etc.)

Then go to phpmyadmin, pick the table you want to repair, and click the "Operations" tab.

You'll find a Table Operations panel. It has an Optimize link. Click it.

Or, you can issue the SQL query

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `#_k2_items`;
```

Notice that this may take a while and your web site will work poorly, if at all, while it's going on.

If you have to do this kind of operation again, use a `WHERE` clause to keep from updating every row in your table. Something like this will do the trick.

```
 UPDATE `#_k2_items` SET `introtext`= replace(`introtext`, '_70.jpg', '_140.jpg')
  WHERE introtext LIKE '%_70.jpg%'
```

Without the `WHERE` clause, MySQL changed every row of your table. The ones where the `replace()` operation did nothing it changed the column to the same value. But it still changed it.  That's why the operation took so long and disrupted your table's optimization.